# How does the React library require its source libraries directly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, commonjs

I was looking through the source code of Facebook's React and saw that throughout the source of the project they don't specify relative paths for loading its own modules. For example, instead of doing `var foo = require('../bar/foobar')` the library uses `var foo = require('foobar')` as if the module was loaded in `node_modules` already for CommonJS to read.

I was just wondering how they managed to do this? I tried looking through their build steps through Grunt but couldn't see any packages that directly accomplish this.

For a more concrete example of the technique I"m talking about, [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/src/core/ReactChildReconciler.js#L17) the library calls the `flattenChildren` module which exists in a [different directory altogether](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/src/utils/flattenChildren.js) without specifying the path.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

React uses a tool called [commoner](https://github.com/reactjs/commoner).  Their configuration of it matches up the lines that look like this:

```
* @providesModule ReactChildReconciler
```

To `require('ReactChildReconciler')` calls.  They also put everything in a single directory, so the paths end up as `require('./ReactChildReconciler')`.

The source code is organized in a structured way, but the module names are globally unique to the repo (and all of facebook's internal code, I think 
<sup>[citation needed]</sup>).  This means there's no ambiguity in what it points to.

---

On the subject, there are also some other magical things in react's code.

The calls to `invariant(assertion, explanation, ...)` and the similar `warning` calls are transformed for the production build by removing the arguments after the first one to save space.  Warning calls are stripped entirely, because they're wrapped in the next piece of magic: development only blocks.

```
if (__DEV__) {
   ...
}
```

Which compiles to:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
   ...
}
```

Which, via envify, compiles to this (in development), and the code runs:

```
if ('development' !== 'production') {
   ...
}
```

And this in production:

```
if ('production' !== 'production') {
   ...
}
```

Which minifies to this:

```
​
```

Comment: i was like "hey the explanation was cut off too.. oh"