# SystemJS: How to prevent that different versions of the same dependency are loaded?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, jspm, systemjs

I am setting up a project with React 0.14.0-alpha2 and React Router 0.13.3. Unfortunately, the router has a dependency to React 0.13.x which is why both versions of React or loaded. This causes weird problems like the following:

> Potentially unhandled rejection [2] Error: Invariant Violation:
>   addComponentAsRefTo(...): Only a ReactOwner can have refs. This
>   usually means that you're trying to add a ref to a component that
>   doesn't have an owner (that is, was not created inside of another
>   component's `render` method). Try rendering this component inside of a
>   new top-level component which will hold the ref.

With SystemJS, is it somehow possible to enforce that only one specific version of a dependency is used? I have already tried the following, but it didn't help:

```
System.versions['react'] = '0.14.0-alpha2';
```

This is a similar problem to the one reported here, just with SystemJS: https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/1003

Comment: I don't understand your goal. If react router needs .13, then you'll need that version. Don't use .14 until it's compatible.

Comment: @WiredPrairie I don't think that the router isn't compatible. Since I am interested in some of the changes in 0.14, I want to see whether it is possible to specify that only React 0.14 is loaded and then I would expect it to just work fine. Otherwise, you are right and I could just use 0.13 instead.

Comment: Temporarily edit the react-router dependency ... see if that works?

Comment: Manually editing the react-router dependency in `config.js` worked for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the React library require its source libraries directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28644357/how-does-the-react-library-require-its-source-libraries-directly)